# Drag n Drop a SVG File

Tags: vb.net

The goal is to have a Drag n Drop operation which works similar like you would just drag a file from the windows explorer and drop it into Word (or similar). The problem is that I get two different results when I try my code. I already search and tried various ways how to fix the problem but I can't achieve a really good solution. This is my current code for the Drag n Drop function:

```
'Drag n Drop
Private Sub IconBoxMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles IconBox.MouseMove
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        Dim dataObj As New DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, New String() {IconPath})
        LayoutBox.DoDragDrop(dataObj, DragDropEffects.Move)
    End If
End Sub
```

This is the result:

[image: results]

On the left if you drag and drop the file from windows explorer to Word. On the right if you drag and drop it with my code to Word. I also tried out other DataFormats to see if it change something but then word (or similar) don't accept the file.

Comment: You use the `mouseMove` handler why not try to use `DragEnter` on the form here is en example: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/360629bb-633c-4eeb-92a4-0af75de893fd/how-to-allow-drag-and-drop-on-picturebox?forum=Vsexpressvcs

Comment: @Mederic I guess you don't understand what I want to achieve. I don't want to drop something in my program (then `DragEnter` would be correct), I want to to drag n drop a file into another program. Like in my example from windows explorer to word. The `DragEnter` Event get not triggered in this operation.

Comment: You mean you have like the icon of your program on the desktop and you just drag a file on top?

Comment: @Mederic you have a picture in a picturebox and want a function so that someone just grab the picture which is in the picturebox and drop it into Paint, Word, Photoshop and so on... You can easily do that with windows explorer itself but how I can do this with code. My function already works but not like you would just do it with windows explorer

Comment: the problem here is there is two possibilities: 1 - you have a picturebox element showing a picture and you want to click and drag that image to the desktop to "save it" for instance. here you have a bitmap rendered in the picturebox so you need to handle that. 2 - the windows explorer approach in windows explorer you drag the file to the application so no bitmap handling. if you could try to really explain with some examples which behaviour you want.

Comment: @Mederic The example is already in my original post.
get .svg file -> drop it to word. I don't want to touch the content of the picture box itself.

Comment: Is word open or closed?

Comment: @Mederic I can not drop a file into a program when it is closed. So yes... it is open..

Comment: Actually it is possible in that case it is the same problem as the link I gave previously where they talk of moving a fileImage to the picturebox of the vb.net application

Comment: @Mederic Ignore the PictureBox. I don't want to drop something in the PictureBox or get the PictureBox.Image out of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172378/discussion-between-mederic-and-marco-sadowski).

Comment: Well, it is not an icon.  SVG is a format that few Windows programs know how to handle, it is pretty exclusive to browsers.  I would guess that you have a shell extension handler installed on your machine that turns an SVG file into something more usable by other programs.  In which case you'd have to do the same thing, perhaps with [this Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Svg/).

Comment: @HansPassant Word can handle .svg files without problems and I also use a SVG Renderer but for other operation. Because in this case I just want to move a file into a program with drag n drop

Comment: You are asking this question because Word did *not* handle that SVG file.  I have no idea what "SVG Renderer" might mean, but it sure sounds a lot like that shell extension I presumed that you have on your machine.  Pretty important that you do this on another machine that is relatively clean so you can see what will happen on your user's machine.  With the expectation that Explorer now won't act any different from what your program does now.

Comment: @HansPassant tested it on a virtual machine: same results. Just googled a bit and found out that a conversion to .emf happen in the background. So I also need to do it in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution. The magical answer is .emf.

1. load the svg document with the svg.net library
2. create a temporary Windows Metafile
3. draw the svg into the metafile
4. start the drag n drop magic

Here is my final code:

```
'Drag n Drop
Private Sub IconBoxMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles IconBox.MouseMove
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        Dim emfTempPath As String = Path.GetTempFileName()

        Try
            Dim svgIcon As SvgDocument = SvgDocument.Open(IconPath)

            Using bufferGraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromHwndInternal(IntPtr.Zero)

                Using metafile = New Metafile(emfTempPath, bufferGraphics.GetHdc())

                    Using graphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(metafile)
                        svgIcon.Draw(graphics)
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
            Dim dataObj As New DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, New String() {emfTempPath})
            LayoutBox.DoDragDrop(dataObj, DragDropEffects.Move)
        Finally
            File.Delete(emfTempPath)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```